# How to request a File in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am able to make a request using the following Request in Google API Explorer:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/asdf?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.EQEo6DJmR0Z-FngYc9nAL5iiidB8TBI7ysBDD6TARiqMtFjmMagLew0oC-vxj9HjojXjja46-5LSEQ
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

How would I then do this request in python? I am currently trying to do it with:

```
api_key = '1122d'
requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/asdf?key=%s' % api_key)
```

But I am getting a 404. How would I do this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You have to authenticate your request](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server). I would recommend using Google's python client to remove a lot of the boilerplate:

`pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

From the docs:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

def build_service(credentials):
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)
  return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
```

Then use the service:

```
from apiclient import errors
try:
  service = build_service(### Credentials here ###)
  file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()

  print 'Title: %s' % file['title']
  print 'Description: %s' % file['description']
  print 'MIME type: %s' % file['mimeType']
except errors.HttpError, error:
  if error.resp.status == 401:
    # Credentials have been revoked.
    # TODO: Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have that installed, how would I download the file, given an `api_key` and `file_id` ?

Comment: Thanks, could you please give an example for the line `service = build_service(### Credentials here ###)` ?